# Fastest way to look for values in an array that are also in another array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I have two arrays, arrayA (3D) that I need to analyse and arrayB that stores values of interest (2D). I want to to return a third array (same dimensions as the original arrayA) that has 1s where a value is one of the values of interest (in arrayB) or 0s if not.

This is the code that I am using:

```
arrayC = np.zeros((arrayA.shape[0], arrayA.shape[1], arrayA.shape[2]))
for k in range(arrayA.shape[2]):
    for i in range(arrayA.shape[0]):
        for j in range(arrayA.shape[1]):
            if arrayA[i][j][k] in arrayB[k]:
                arrayC[i][j][k] = 1
```

This takes forever (several minutes) for arrayA 1000x1000x10 and I need to find a way to make it way faster. I know that I can speed it up by working on a flattened array which I've implemented (I've left the code here as above just to make it clear what is happening) and then again reshaping in the end, but I am looking for a further improvement.

(I've also tried with np.where, but I cannot make it work with a range condition)

Comment: Just as a sidenote: you can create pre-initialized arrays in the shape of another array like this `arrayC = np.zeros_like(arrayA)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [numpy.isin](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html):

```
c = np.zeros_like(a)
for k in range(a.shape[2]):
    c[:, :, k] = np.isin(a[:, :, k], b[k])
```

In a rough test on my machine, for a with shape (1000, 1000, 10) and b with shape (1000, 500) this takes 1.55 seconds, while your version takes 50.3 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the expected result in a vectorized way with `np.isin` and `np.where`:

```
arrayC = np.where([np.isin(arrayA[i], arrayB[i])
                   for i in range(len(arrayB))], 1, 0)
```

Comment: First version was indeed wrong. This one should be good because `arrayB[i]` is a flat array. And `timeit` says that it is 30% faster than [Mephy's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61250589/3545273) solution.